# No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, dataset, svc

my problem seems to be easy but i have no idea how to resolve it.
So i got an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

when i try to import datasets and svc, but in my opinion i had installed all required packages already

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install -U scikit-learn
Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
```

using python 3.4

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from c:\python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)
```

also using Eclipse IDE with PyDev, working on Windows

Someone know what is going on?

Comment: Is your default python version 3.4?

Comment: no, deflaut version is 3.6.1 but i already unistalled it

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found an answer. If someone has the same problem, in my case IDE had linked wrong interpreter